# How to animate expansion of grid layout?

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering how I would animate the expansion of a grid layout. As you can see in the code I have 4 divs. Two of them are displayed and the other two are displayed only when the checkbox is checked.

When the checkbox is checked another row is added, that contains div3 and div4. How do I make that expansion animated? Preferably keeping the size of the grids. I don't want the animation to affect the (non-existent) margins. I also want to do this without javascript. Is it possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="div1">Hello</div>
        <div class="div2">Hello2</div>
        <div class="div3">Hello3</div>
        <div class="div4">Hello4</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.toggle {
    width: 100%;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    width: 20%;
    border: solid black 2px;
}

.div1 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.div2 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.div3 {
    display: none;
}

.div4 {
    display: none;
}

.toggle:checked ~ .grid > .div3 {
    display: block;
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}

.toggle:checked ~ .grid > .div4 {
    display: block;
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
}
```

I want the div container to slide down to make room for the added row. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This might help @Hugo https://css-tricks.com/animating-css-grid-how-to-examples/

Comment: Maybe this too https://youtube.com/shorts/3gNOoYzarNo?feature=share

Comment: Not possible with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. I put my grid into another grid. Then I simply used fr as the way to size my rows on the div the main grid was put into. Which led to the possibility of transforming the grid rows from 0fr to 1fr. And thats it.

```css
.toggle {
    width: 100%;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    width: 20%;
    border: solid black 2px;
}

.div1 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.div2 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.wrapper {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 2;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 0fr;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: grid-template-rows 200ms;
}

.div3 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
    min-height: 0;
}

.div4 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
    min-height: 0;
}

.toggle:checked ~ .grid > .wrapper {
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="div1">Hello</div>
        <div class="div2">Hello2</div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="div3">Hello3</div>
            <div class="div4">Hello4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, if you have different very differently sized rows in your grid. For example one that is 0.05fr and one that is 1fr the animation will become "laggy". What you can do about that is put the wrapper grid into another wrapper grid. Then you dont animate that grid with your actual rows and instead animate the child of the first grid or the parent of your actual grid with the same method.

Kind of a weird workaround but it's one way to solve it without redoing much.